# Unable to add member through feature "Request to add members"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there any possibility to recreate Microsoft Teams' "Request to add members" using Microsoft Graph (without recreating the approval flow)?

I have managed to [add members/owners to a Team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using Graph Explorer like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members/$ref
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{userId}"
}
```

Recently Microsoft added the "Request to add members" feature to Microsoft Teams that permits members of a team to add people to a Team which results in an Approval Request in Teams.

When I try to add a member inside a Team *as* a Member through Graph Explorer, however, I get an `HTTP 204 - Success` response but the Member is not shown in the Team and no Approval Request is sent/generated.

When I check Group Membership, however, the added User *is* present (it is also visible from Office365 Admin Center):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/members/
```

After a long time (4 to 8 hours for my tests) the User is finally added (without an Approval Request):

```
[Yesterday 4:17 PM] 
  John Doe joined the team.
```

Is there a possibility at the moment to create a "pending request" on-behalf a user using Microsoft Graph or is this a missing feature?

I've also [created a UserVoice request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/38207560-add-support-request-to-add-members-feature-throu) for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Your question doesn't include any example code showing how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur , there is more detail about this scenario :

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue is documented in [Membership changes in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#membership-changes-in-microsoft-teams):

> We recommend that when you add an owner, you also add that user as a member. 
>   If a team has an owner who is not also a member, ownership and membership changes might not show up immediately in Microsoft Teams. 
>   In addition, different apps and APIs will handle that differently. 
>   For example, Microsoft Teams will show teams that the user is either a member or an owner of, while the Microsoft Teams PowerShell cmdlets and the `/me/joinedTeams` API will only show teams the user is a member of. 
>   To avoid confusion, add all owners to the members list as well.
>
> Known issue: when `DELETE /groups/{id}/owners` is called, the user is also removed from the `/groups/{id}/members` list. To work around this, we recommend that you remove the user from both owners and members, then wait 10 seconds, then add them back to members.
>
> When adding and removing members and owners, don't put braces { } around the ID.
>
> - Fast: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315/members/48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038/$ref`
> - Slow: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{02bd9fd6-8f93-4758-87c3-1fb73740a315}/members/{48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038}/$ref`
>
> Similarly, if the `userId` in the URL or payload is expressed as a UPN rather than as a GUID, the performance will be slower.
>
> - Fast: `48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038`
> - Slow: `john@example.com`
>
> When the slower path is taken, if a current team member or owner is signed in to the Microsoft Teams application/website, the change will be reflected within an hour.
>   If none of those users are signed in to the Microsoft Teams application/website, the change will not be reflected until an hour after one of them signs in.

Comment: Hi again, i don't understand why my answer was deleted by a moderator without any details but anyway ;^)

Comment: I do not face issue about membership changes or slow/fast method. Can you confirm that there is not method at the moment to replicate the feature “Request to add members” in teams through Microsoft Graph API ?

Also if you have any intel about a roadmap for this feature AND if you can share it i'd be curious to know :) 

Thx for your time

Comment: Your answer wasn't an answer to your question, it was additional detail that belongs in the question itself. I have no information on roadmaps so I cannot comment on if/when they might add this workflow.

Comment: ok thx for feedback ;) i added  detail to question sorry for error.